# Reconstructing Convex Functional from gradient

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, vector-analysis, subgradient

Suppose that $f\in \Gamma_0(H)$, that is $f$ is a lsc, convex, and proper functional from a Hilbert space $H$ to the base-field $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it possible to reconstruct $f$, from the Fenchel-Moreau subdifferential 
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\partial f: dom(H) \rightrightarrows H\\
& \partial f: x\mapsto   \{
y \in H :(\forall z \in H)\, \langle y,\, z-x\rangle \leq f(z)-f(x)
\}?
\end{aligned}
$$

---

**Intuition**

I expect (more or less) since if we take the special case where

- $H=\mathbb{R}^d$ and $f$ differentiable (ie: $\partial f = \{\nabla f\}$),
- there is some $p \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $f(y)=0$, 
  then the *[Fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem)* implies that
  $$
  f(x)= \int_{\gamma_{[x:y]}} \nabla f(s) \cdot ds,
  $$
  where $\gamma_{[x:y]}$ is any smooth curve joining $x$ to $y$.
  *Therefore, in this case, the subdifferential may be used to reconstruct the function $f$ perfectly.*

Comment: By "perfectly", do you mean "up to a constant"?

Comment: Oh I mean up to a constant, which we'll require to be $0$...making it unique.

Comment: It's probably using a hammer to kill a fly, but check out Theorem B in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102977253).

Comment: Ahah, funny coincidence, actually I just used a very similar theorem of Rockafellar from one of his 1966 papers: "Characterization of the subdifferentials of convex functions".  Thanks, tough this is very interesting also :)

Comment: I am late to the party, but I would like to point out that the paper mentioned by Theo Bendit says that the 1966 paper has some flaws in some of the proofs.